# Sql queries from this month, and users who have sent more posts

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to show users more posts have from this month added to the list. But does not work.

```
SELECT *,SUM(post_id) FROM `posts` Where YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 18
```

sql table data :

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `api_id`, `user_id`, `group_id`, `message`, `mentioned`, `attached`, `posttags`, `comments`, `reshares`, `date`, `date_lastedit`, `date_lastcomment`, `ip_addr`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 0, 'text', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1360378616, 0, 1360378616, 0);
```

Comment: Selecting any columns that are not part of the GROUPing is illegal in most SQL dialects. (MySQL tolerates it, based on server config, but then delivers column values from one row in the group randomly.)

Comment: read  http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting question

Answer (score 1):

You should specify column name in select clause as same that of  in group by clause 
try this.

```
SELECT user_id,SUM(post_id) FROM `posts` Where YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 0 , 18
```